# Qt подсветка синтаксиса как в visual studio

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Начал изучать Qt. В редакторе Qt Creator мне не нравится цвета подсветки синтаксиса.

Есть ли какие-нибудь наборы, которые заменяют цвета подсветки на аналогичные из visual studio?

P.S. настраивать каждый цвет вручную слишком муторно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё же нашел неплохой стиль https://github.com/yhvicey/Visual-Studio-2015-Dark-Theme-for-Qt-Creator

xml файл нужно пихнуть в AppData\Roaming\QtProject\qtcreator\styles (если нет папки styles - нужно создать).